# Compare lists of dictionaries based on values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries as:

```
old_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-20'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Google', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

new_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-12'},
            {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

I am interested in getting the list element from new_data only if:

1. Company in new_data is not in old_data
2. If company is in both new_data and old_data, only if logged_in time in new_data is later than in old_data

Expected outcome:

```
[{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
 {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
 {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

So far, I tried:

```
filter_data = []
for nd in new_data:
    if nd['company'] not in [d['company'] for d in old_data]:
        filter_data.append(nd)
    elif nd['company'] in [d['company'] for d in old_data]:
        date_ = # logged_in time of the company from old_data
        filter_data.append(nd if nd['logged_in']> date_)
filter_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
old_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-20'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Google', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

new_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-12'},
            {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

old_data = {i["company"]: i["logged_in"] for i in old_data}

result = []
for i in new_data:
    if i["company"] not in old_data:
        result.append(i)
    elif i["logged_in"] > old_data[i["company"]]:
        result.append(i)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
 {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
 {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

**Note:**

- Convert `old_data` to a dictionary for easy lookup.

Comment: You could eliminate the datetime conversions and just compare the strings since they are ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @benvc Thanks...did not think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, assuming that company names in `old_data` are not repeated:

```
old_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-20'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Google', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

new_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-12'},
            {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
# Make dictionary mapping company names to logged in times
old_data_dict = {d['company']: d['logged_in'] for d in old_data}
# Make result by comparing logged in times to previous value or empty string
result = [d for d in new_data if d['logged_in'] > old_data_dict.get(d['company'], '')]
# Print result
print(*result, sep='\n')
# {'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'}
# {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}
# {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}
```

EDIT: If `old_data` may contain multiple dictionaries with the same company name, you can define `old_data_dict` as follows instead:

```
old_data_dict = {}
for d in old_data:
    old_data_dict[d['company']] = max(d['logged_in'],
                                      old_data_dict.get(d['company'], ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a reversed-index dictionary `old_dic` it becomes easy:

```
old_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-20'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Google', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

new_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-12'},
            {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

old_dic = {o["company"]: {"logged_in": o["logged_in"]} for o in old_data}

result = [
    n for n in new_data 
    if n["company"] not in s or 
       n["logged_in"] > old_dic[n["company"]]["logged_in"]
]
```

outputs:

```
[{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
 {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
 {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to pick-up where you left off:

```
def find_logged_in(company, olddata):
    for od in olddata:
        if od['company']==company:
            return od['logged_in']
    return None


filter_data = []
for nd in new_data:
    if nd['company'] not in [d['company'] for d in old_data]:
        filter_data.append(nd)
    elif nd['company'] in [d['company'] for d in old_data]:
        date_ = find_logged_in(nd['company'], old_data) 
        if nd['logged_in'] > date_:
            filter_data.append(nd)
filter_data
```

Result:

```
[{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
 {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
 {'company': 'Wiki', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using pandas:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
a = DataFrame(new_data+old_data).groupby('company',as_index=False).max().to_dict('record')
filter_data = [x for x in a if x not in b]
```